# How to find with in a file the last updated picture using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following script

```
   Sub Picture()
    Dim picname As String
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim pasteAt As Integer
    Dim lThisRow As Long
    Dim present As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim PicCode As String
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  

      Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 2).ColumnWidth = 20
      Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 2).RowHeight = 100
      Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 2).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
      Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 2).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
      Set MyRange = Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, 1)
       lThisRow = 1 'This is the start row
        Do While (Cells(lThisRow, 1) <> "")
            pasteAt = lThisRow
            Cells(pasteAt, 2).Select 'This is where picture will be inserted (column)
            picname = Cells(lThisRow, 1) 'This is the picture name
          

  present = Dir("C:\Users\User\Documents\albumForExcel\" & picname & ".jpg")
        If present <> "" Then
          Cells(pasteAt, 2).Select
           Call ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\User\Documents\albumForExcel\" & picname & 
          ".jpg", _
           msoCTrue, msoCTrue, Left:=Cells(pasteAt, 2).Left, Top:=Cells(pasteAt, 2).Top, Width:=100, 
      Height:=100).Select
            Else
            Cells(pasteAt, 2) = "No Picture Found"
       End If
        lThisRow = lThisRow + 1
    Loop
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

  End Sub
```

I case picture does not exists in the current file I want to import the picture from a backup file . The picture might have more that one instance in the backup file .How do I insert the last updates instance

Thank

Dov

Comment: I don't get how your pictures are stored. What do you mean exactly with "backup file". Which format ?

Comment: The pictures are stored as jpg files and the backup file is a system folder where the pictures are stored as jpg files as well .